# Angular Element Component doesn't update when I add object from property

Tags: angular, angular-elements

I have Angular Element Component (with Angular 8) which has 2 props. When I try to push something in the array the Shadow-Root doesn't re-render it(the counter yes instead). How I can force the rendering when i push an object in the component?

Thanks

This is the Component class

```js
export class CounterComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  counter: number;

  @Input()
  images: Array<any>;

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.counter = 0;
    this.images = [];
  }

  add() {
    this.counter++;
  }

  reduce() {
    this.counter--;
  }

  @Input()
  addImage() {
    this.images.push({ ciccio: 'piccio'}); //no rerender
    this.cdr.detectChanges(); // Error cdr is null
  }
}
```

AppModule

```js
import { BrowserModule, platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Injector } from '@angular/core';

import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CounterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  entryComponents: [CounterComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {

  }

  ngDoBootstrap( ) {
    const el = createCustomElement(CounterComponent, {injector: this.injector});
    customElements.define('count-component', el);
  }
 }
```

This is the component template

```html
<div style="display: flex;justify-content: center;flex-direction: column">
    <h1>Counter component</h1>
    <h4>Count ---> {{counter}}</h4>
    <button (click)="add()">Increase</button>
    <button (click)="reduce()">Decrease</button>
</div>

<h3>
Images {{images.length}}
</h3>
```

Comment: have created a demo( https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrcsj4 ) based on your code. The ui seems to be rendering the changed array length on addition of new alements to array. Can you please explain a bit more about the issue that you are facing.

Comment: @SiddhantPatra your demo is irrelevant, he's using Angular Elements (`@angular/elements`) which works a little differently than "normal" Angular.

Comment: @Input() set counter(val) {
console.log(val)
}

Comment: add your code to stackblitz , so that everybody can understand

Comment: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/nt5YkmCpOgm2UJcR

Comment: Have you tried changing the actual array?    I.e. `this.images = [...this.images, { ciccio: 'piccio'}];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, which will actually change the value of the images property on your component, allowing it to see the change:

```
  @Input()
  addImage() {
    this.images = [...this.images, { ciccio: 'piccio'}]; // should render
  }
```

Plunk: [here](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/aPROUbfm90EIr2h9)

Comment: This works due to Angular detecting the change of the `images` reference. Immutability definitely works best for change detection.

Answer (score 1):

According to ["Angular Elements Overview"](https://angular.io/guide/elements#angular-elements-overview) in Angular's documentation:

> We are working on custom elements that can be used by web apps built on other frameworks. A minimal, self-contained version of the Angular framework will be injected as a service to support the component's change-detection and data-binding functionality. For more about the direction of development, check out this [video presentation](https://youtu.be/Z1gLFPLVJjY).

As said in [8:28 in the video presentation attached above](https://youtu.be/Z1gLFPLVJjY?t=508), dependency injection works for custom elements in Angular Elements. Therefore, inject `ChangeDetectorRef` into your custom element and call `detectChanges()` when mutating your `images` array, like so:

```
export class CounterComponent /* ... */ {
    constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }   
    /* ... */
    addImage() {
        this.images.push({ ciccio: 'piccio'});
        this.cdr.detectChanges(); // change detection will detect the change in `images` and render
    }
}
```

Comment: i reiceve this error --> Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of undefined

Comment: @Bonfry Sounds like `ChangeDetectorRef` wasn't *actually* injected. Did you [pass an `Injector` instance as an option when you called `createCustomElement()`](https://youtu.be/Z1gLFPLVJjY?t=558) to create your custom `CounterComponent` element?

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Input()
  addImage() {
     this.ngZone.run(() => {
        this.images.push({ ciccio: 'piccio'}); //no rerender
     });
  }
```

Can you try injecting NgZone from @angular/core and run inside it?

Comment: angular elements doesn't inject ngZone in the componet

Comment: sorry, I didn't get. Are you saying we can't inject ngZone in component?